# Checking if a word is a palindrome by reversing a stack without using any prewritten functions

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#define Max 100000
class Stack {
private:
    int top =-1;
    char letters[Max];

public:
    void setTop(int t) {
        top = t;
    }
    int getTop() {
        return top;
    }
    bool isEmptyStack() {
        if (top == -1) {
            return true;
        }
        else{ return false;
    }

   }

    char push(char x,int s) {
        if (top != s - 1){
            top++;
            x = letters[top];
            return x;
        }
       
    }
    char pop() {
        if ((isEmptyStack())==false){
            cout << "the deleted value is: " << l[top]<<endl;
            top--;
            return l[top];
        }


    }
   
 
};
void reverse(char letters[], char temp[], int size, Stack stack) {
    int i=0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        stack.push(letters[i],size);
    }
    i = 0;
    cout << temp<<endl;
    while (stack.isEmptyStack() == false)
    {
        letters[-1] = stack.getTop();
        stack.pop();
        stack.push(letters[i],size);
        i++;
    }
     /*   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            cout << temp[i];
        }*/
}


int myStringLength(const char* letter)
{
    for (int i = 0, c = 0; letter[i] != '\0'; i++, c++) {

        if (letter[i] != '\0')
            for (; letter[i] != '\0'; i++, c++)
                if (letter[i] == '\0') break;
        return c;
    }
}
int main()
//initializes the main function
{
    Stack stack;
    string w;
    std::cout << "Enter a Word: ";
    getline(cin,w);


    char* letters = &w[0];
    // sets the character text array to set the number of characters equal to the size of the string
   
    //calls the processData function 
    
    std::cout << letters<<endl;
     int size = myStringLength(letters);
    reverse(letters, letters, size, stack);




    return 0;//returns the function at 0.
}
```

I set out to create a program that will check if a word is a palindrome(meaning it is spelled the same normally and if the word is reversed.)  I am not yet at that point that is just the final objective.  In my code, I have created a stack class because I wanted to feel the satisfaction of getting the same result using my own code. My problem is the stack is not reversing it is returning some weird characters that I don't have the keys on my keyboard to replicate.
The desired outcome should be word's reversed characters.
if the word is **food** the function should be returning **doof**.  I have already compared the reversed stack to the original and printed the final statement.  I fixed the char letters[];

Comment: *because I wanted to feel the satisfaction of getting the same result using my own code* I suggest you use `std::stack` first, to ensure what you are writing actually works correctly.  Then replace `std::stack` with your own home-made stack class.  You are trying to do a goal (palindrome solving),  and you don't know if the foundation you're using to solve the problem is faulty or not.  Make sure the goal can be accomplished first by using components that work (`std::stack`), then go back and use your own components.

Comment: `int myStringLength(const char* letter)` -- I know you say you want to use your own functions, but I believe you're going a little overboard here.  Why not use `strlen`?  Proper usage of the language requires you to know how to use some of the basic library functions.  Second, `#include <string>` is for the `std::string` class, but you make no usage of it.  If anything that should be `#include <cstring>`

Comment: I have used cout statements after the push function worked perfectly it is either the pop function or when it checks if the stack is empty.

Comment: *I have used cout statements after the push function worked perfectly* -- If it worked perfectly, why is there an issue?

Comment: int myStringLength function is also working perfectly I printed the returned value from that function and it works perfectly.

Comment: It is the pop function in the stack class or the  while (!stack.theStackIsEmpty())
    {
        // assign each popped item back to the original array
        letters[index++] = stack.top;
        stack.pop();
    }

Comment: [Rubber duckie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) would like you to explain to it the size of this array: `char letters[];`

Comment: `char letters[];` -- This is not valid C++.  Second, even if that was valid C++, your `Stack` implementation has buffer overrun issues.  That's why I suggested you to use working components first.  Then once you get it working with `std::stack`, `std::string`, etc.  **then** you go and try and do this yourself with your own classes.  And once you try to implement this with your own classes, you have yet another issue with `Stack`, since `Stack` is not safely copyable and assignable (unless you use the rule of 3).  Frying pan into the fire type stuff.

Comment: There are no unit tests for your Stack. Write them first to verify your class is correct.

Comment: Bottom line -- your `Stack` class is broken, and the only "repair" is to rewrite it.  This: `char letters[];` is the elephant in the room.

Comment: `myStringLength` could be a simple loop with a counter and a return statement. Something like `int myStringLength(const char *letter) { int i = 0; for ( ; letter[i] != '\0'; i++, ); return i; };`

Comment: Compile the code with a stricter set of warnings and then resolve the detected warnings. This should get rid of most of the bugs we've been warning about. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/8jvYdGh8r

Comment: You don’t need any stack. That may well be the most important piece of advice to start with. Iterate over the string from both ends towards the middle and check if the first half of the string is in fact a mirror image of the other half. If that is the case, then it’s a palindrome. That’s all, that’s it. No stack is needed. If your code produces weird characters, run it with `valgrind` and fix all memory management errors first. It will tell you where exactly they happen.

Comment: Why not just use a `for` loop? That's even simpler than a `stack`, if your goal is to make everything the simplest.

Comment: You have too many errors for a single SO question. Focus on one aspect at a time. Quick example: don't rely on user input until you are convinced the rest of your code works. Instead of reading `w` from `cin`, initialize it to your test case, as in `string w = "food";`. Taking this another step, you can eliminate `myStringLength()` from consideration until you know the rest of your code works; initialize `int size = 4;` (the length of your hardcoded `"food"`). Keep trimming and focusing until you have a specific issue and a short, [mre] demonstrating just that issue.

Comment: @supercarlover *"it is either the pop function or when it checks if the stack is empty."* -- this can be the basis of a good [mre]. Drop the palindrome goal for now and focus on the pop. Reduce your `main` function to pushing the character `'a'` on the stack, verifying the top of the stack, popping the character, then verifying that the stack is empty. If you need to push both `'a'` and `'b'`, then do so. But focus your test on **one** aspect of your current code. Test each piece in isolation before testing the whole program.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using a simple function instead of a `Stack` then you could use the following program since it is much more simple than your `Stack` version and hence **less-error prone**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
bool checkIfPalindroom(const std::string &str)
{
    for(int i=0;i<(str.size()/2);i++)
    {
         if (str[i] != str[str.size() - i - 1])
         {
             return false;//if this if is satisfied even once, return false
         }
    
    }
    return true;//if the control flow reaches here this will mean that no if was satisfied and hence return true
}
int main()
{
    std::string myString = "Somearbitrarystring";
    
    
    if(checkIfPalindroom(myString))//call the function
    {
        std::cout<<"The given string: "<<myString <<" is a palindrome"<<std::endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout<<"The given string: "<<myString<<" is not a palindrome"<<std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```